# Как установить библиотеку с github?

Tags: ubuntu, github, git-clone

Есть у меня pymorphy2 0.8, но мне нужен pymorphy2 ветка master. Она лежит тут https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2/ . Как мне заменить их? Я понимаю что клонировать. Но куда клонировать с github, в какую папку. И чтобы потом нормально работало через терминал. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта команда все сделает:

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2.git@master
```