# Как установить в num2t4ru?

Tags: python, windows, github

Как установить num2t4ru, если через пип не уславливается? Заранее спасибо! Я еще новичок, и решил разобрать код из интернета.

библиотека: https://github.com/Yuego/num2t4ru

Я еще не устанавливал его. Я хочу сделать проект ютубера (ссылка на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeGvaDaraI&ab_channel=%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%A5%D0%BE%E2%84%A2-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5IT%21 )

Comment: Побольше информации добавьте в вопрос: как именно устанавливали, какая ошибка вышла, где вы эту библиотеку вообще нашли/узнали про неё (ссылку дайте) и т.д.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613574/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-github?rq=1

Comment: Ага, ну вот посмотрите по ссылке, которую вам дали в комментарии, там приведён пример, как поставить что-то прямо из гитхаба. Хотя там может быть у вас другой случай. А по вашей ссылке не написано, как ставить эту либу? У меня просто нет возможности сейчас посмотреть гитхаб.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека нужна по факту для преобразования числа в текст, по типу `1 = "один"`. Нашел такую альтернативу:

```
pip install num2words
```

эту строку

```
from num2t4ru import num2text
```

меняем на эту

```
from num2words import num2words
```

и эту

```
text = "Сейч+ас " + num2text(now.hour) + " " + num2text(now.minute)
```

на эту

```
text = "Сейч+ас " + num2words(now.hour, lang='ru') + " " + num2words(now.minute, lang='ru')
```

Результат такой же, которого добивались и в видео.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Такая же ситуация. Короче, я понял, что эта библиотека отвечает за время. Можешь использовать библиотеку datatime, там есть и дата и время. За библиотеку num2t4ru ничего не могу подсказать, сам не знаю.